# Javascript equivalent of jquery ajaxStop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have multiple ajax request launched at the same time and I want to be able to call a function when they end.

I saw the jQuery function : `ajaxStop()` but I can't use jQuery in my project.

Does anyone know how to do the same in javascript only?

Thanks for help !

Comment: ajaxStop likely doesn't do what you expect it to do. It simly cancels the event handler it doesn't prevent the ajax call. The Ajax HTTP call is async and doesn't provide a mechanism to say ot the server, "ok I don't want this anymore"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the abort method to stop an http call.

```
//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

Comment: This doesn't "stop the HTTP call". It simply aborts the Javascript event waiting for it to return. The HTTP call still carries on and returns as expected, just nothing is waiting anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can build a little utility function which check readystate (accessible globally):

```
window.abortAjaxCalls = function(xhr) {
    if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
        xhr.abort();
    }
}

window.abortAjaxCalls(xhr);
```